# template restrictions in C++

Tags: java, c++, generics, templates

I am creating a template class in C++ for numeric operations and I want to restrict it to only numbers or similar numeric types. My question is that is there any way in C++ to restrict a template class to a specific domain as in java its simply:

```
public class num<N extends Number>{}
```

answers will be appreciated

Comment: This is called F-bound Polymorphism, and in C++ the pattern is [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

Comment: @imnota4 Sure c++ templates can be restricted like Java generics, they are plenty more powerful...

Comment: @Deduplicator Thank you, but an example might be more helpful.

Comment: Look for `std::enable_if_t` and `std::is_base_of`.

Comment: also look at std::is_arithmetic / std::is_integral / std::is_floating_point if what you are wanting to restrict is specifically numbers

Comment: That's more of a workaround than it is a feature, but you're right, it'll work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let assume we have:

```cpp
class Number { };
class ExtendedNumber : public Number { };
class NotNumber { };
```

And we want to build UsesNumber class like this:

```cpp
int main() {
    UsesNumber<Number> u1; // fine
    UsesNumber<ExtendedNumber> u2; // fine
    UsesNumber<NotNumber> u3; // compile error
}
```

c++20 solution using constraints and concepts looks like this:

```cpp
#include <concepts>
template<typename N>
requires std::derived_from<N, Number>
class UsesNumber{ };
```

For c++17 you can use **enable_if** with **is_base_of**

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
template<
    typename N,
    typename = std::enable_if_t< std::is_base_of_v<Number, N> >
>  
class UsesNumber{ };
```

P.S. Note that in **ExtendedNumber** we have to derive **Number** as **public**.

And for anyone who needs c++11 version

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
template<
    typename N,
    typename = typename std::enable_if< std::is_base_of<Number, N>::value >::type
>  
class UsesNumber{ };
```

Answer (score -2):

For normal templates, you write:

```
template <typename T>
```

or

```
template <class T>
```

and this will accept any type.

Therefore, you should write:

```
template <size_t T>
```

And you effectively limit T to being a (decimal) number.

Comment: That's not accurate. I can still use a built in types even if I use class.

Comment: You're right: class is simply a recommendation in that case. The usage of using size_t or int64_t is, however, still a correct answer to the original question.

Comment: Hmm, why is this down-voted? Isn't this exactly what the OP wants?

Comment: `template <size_t T>` means `T` is a *value* of type `size_t`, not a *type* (restricted to some category)